# 2016 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Science Fiction & Fantasy's [fourth moderator election](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: rand al'thor] [image: Null]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Please join me in thanking Keen who was elected in the [very first election](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election/1) and stepped away from the site shortly before this announcement.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [on the election page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/4658187521228800/0).

Answer (score 48):

**Congratulations to our new moderators!**

As a losing candidate, I send my personal congratulations to both Rand al'Thor and Null. I wish you and the entire community the best. I’m sure you’ll both work for the good of the site. I can’t imagine this is an easy role to take on – good luck to you and our entire moderation team – and thanks in advance for the work you’re about to put in.

Thanks also to everybody else who ran. There were more good candidates than positions available, and I think that’s an endorsement for the health of our site.

Finally, thanks to anybody who voted for me. It really means a lot.

---

**@Gilles and @Keen:** Thank you for all the work you’ve put into the site, both as some of our first moderators and as regular posters. I’m sorry you felt the need to leave the site behind, and I wish you both the best of luck in the future.

Comment: I appreciate that you put yourself up (more than once as well). You've put a lot of hard work into the inner workings of this site and have been very helpful (both from my first-hand experience and seeing the way you treat users). Good luck next time mate!

Comment: A very gracious speech. I'm pretty sure you'll be among the frontiest of front-runners next time around.

Comment: You were my third pick, too bad it didn't work out for either of us.

Comment: @JackBNimble - At this rate you may end up winning by [default](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhvIISDoarU)

Comment: You always have something classy to say. I won't give away my other two votes, but my first vote went to you :)

Comment: Thank you! You were one of my three choices, and I hope you run again next time because I'm sure you would make a great mod.

Comment: Thanks from me too! You were one of two tied for my 3rd choice, and would have been an excellent mod. I hope Null and I will do as well as you would have :-)

Answer (score 30):

**Thank you to all who voted for me and to everyone who expressed their congratulations. Thank you also to all the candidates for a good race.** There were many excellent candidates who would have made great moderators, and I hope they consider running in the next election.

Thank you also to Keen for all his efforts. Your presence will be sorely missed, especially as I learn how to use the mod tools!

I look forward to serving this community and doing my best to help ensure that everyone here has the best experience possible.

Comment: I've seen you man the review queues and offer helpful comments quite often. I trust you will make a fine moderator! Congrats mate.

Comment: You've summed up my sentiments perfectly. I look forward to working with you.

Comment: @randal'thor Likewise, I look forward to working with you and the other mods.

Comment: Many congratulations on your new position -- I have no doubt you will do an excellent job! :)

Comment: @Slytherincess Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

**Congratulations to you both.** I hope your time as a moderator is happier than mine was and that you both hold fast to the qualities that made people vote for you in the first place; honesty, openness and a genuine desire to make this site the best that it can be.

[image] [image]

A special word to Rand. You've had to deal with some very open (and harsh) criticism during this campaign and you've shown amazing resilience in not taking the bait that's been offered, something that bodes extremely well for your time as mod. **Kudos**.

Comment: Thank you! I will keep your advice in mind, especially your advice to genuinely try to make this site the best possible -- I think [your obvious love for this site is one of your best qualities](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7327/31936).

Comment: A big thank you from me. I've greatly appreciated your support over the course of the election. As a mod I'll try to emulate the things you did *right*, while avoiding your mistakes :-)

Answer (score 18):

Congratulations to Null.

[Since I do not trust rand al'thor as a moderator, I have requested the deletion of my account](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/34495?m=27234630#27234630).

To the Science Fiction & Fantasy community: so long, and thanks for all the fish.

— Gilles a.k.a. user56

Comment: <comments removed> cut it out. Expressing disapproval isn't against the rules.

Comment: @Kevin - The mode and method seem very short of "be nice", but I guess we shall have to agree to disagree.

Comment: For the record (as the person this answer is being negative about), I'd be much happier if we could put it all behind us. In its current state, the post is negative but not *abusive*. @Valorum I appreciate the gesture, but stirring this up again will probably only make things worse.

Comment: @Kevin - Expressing disapproval is okay, but rudeness and belittling language is [explicitly against the rules](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). If I were to make a post that calls another user a two-faced bully I'm sure it'll get flagged and removed.

Comment: One option here is to just unlink the middle paragraph, if the chat message is what is drawing ire.

Answer (score 6):

To [@Null](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31936/null) and [@rand al'thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394/rand-althor)

> Night gathers, and now my watch begins. It shall not end until my death. I shall take no wife, hold no lands, father no children. I shall wear no crowns and win no glory. I shall live and die at my post. I am the sword in the darkness. I am the watcher on the walls. I am the fire that burns against the cold, the light that brings the dawn, the horn that wakes the sleepers, the shield that guards the realms of men. I pledge my life and honor to the Night's Watch, for this night and all the nights to come.

To [@Keen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/user1027):

> And now his watch is ended

Comment: Quotes from: [Nights' Watch Vows](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Night's_Watch#Vows)

Comment: Omg,  no wife, hold no lands, father no children. I am happy to not be a mod here then :p

Comment: **Death is lighter than a feather, duty heavier than a mountain. Peace favour our swords.**

Comment: *Spaceship!* - Benny

Answer (score 3):

Congrats to Null and Rand.

Most of your duties will consist of chanting "WE ARE THE MODS, WE ARE THE MODS, WE ARE WE ARE WE ARE THE MODS!" and terrorizing British seaside towns like Brighton on Bank Holidays.

May you both be the just and worthy Big Brothers we wished for.

Less optimistically:

Comment: Thank you! That second link might be especially appropriate, and I'd appreciate it if you'd try to not make it even more of a jungle for the mod team. :)

Comment: @Null - I make mistakes from time to time, but I ferociously defend our mods, even when we disagree (although I will speak up if I think something unfair has happened.  I have been striving to make SF&F a well oiled machine for months, and **I am wholeheartedly in your corner.**  I also voted for you, FWIW.  You can count on me, despite my occasional missteps.  **"YOU HAVE MY AXE!"**  I shall use it to chop down as much jungle vegetation as possible.  :)

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=24172963#24172963

Comment: Thanks for your vote. I know you do your best to behave. :) I definitely hope you speak up if you think something unfair has happened, and I hope the rest of the community feels comfortable doing so as well.