# Are the round-by-round election vote counts available?

Tags: support, election

See title.

Are the round-by-round election results and the vote counts available?

Comment: Is [this breakdown](http://www.opavote.com/results/4658187521228800/0) the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: @alexwlchan, yes excellent.   Is that linked to from somewhere obvious?

Comment: @alexwlchan, okay.   Duh, I guess I was skimming too fast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the links to the results were provided when the [election results](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8091/31936) were posted:

> For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [on the election page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/4658187521228800/0).